# Integrate flutter database with strapi

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, mobile, strapi

I'm new to flutter and strapi. Currently I have a simple mobile app, and I need to store some information, it's not a lot, about 5 parameters, but it would be a lot of records (possibly millions of rows in the table). I don't have any database configuration.

Also, I'm using strapi to get some images for my app. I was thinking that maybe I can add the informacion I need there, in strapi, but I've heard that It doesn't work very well with a lot of data.

How can I integrate a database (like SQLite) with strapi in a flutter app? If maybe I could get some guidance or steps on how to do this I would really appreciate it.

I have a simple app, and I'm using strapi to get some images for it, only GET requests, I'm not posting anything on strapi.